# Systemd can´t find exec file

Tags: linux, systemd, nixos

My systemd service can´t find the folder but when I try it in the shell it works.

I am using nixos and my config of the service is the following:

```
  {
  systemd.services.intranet_dev = {
    wantedBy = [ "multi-user.target" ];
    description = "Intranet Dev Server";

    serviceConfig = {
        Type = "simple";
        User = "gitlabrunner";
        Group = "users";
        WorkingDirectory = "/home/gitlabrunner/intranet/intranet_dev";
        ExecStart = "/home/gitlabrunner/intranet/intranet_dev/bin/intranet_dev start";
        ExecStop = "/home/gitlabrunner/intranet/intranet_dev/bin/intranet_dev stop";
        Restart = "always";

        # Filesystem
        ProtectHome = true;
        PrivateDevices = true;
        ProtectKernelTunables = true;
        ProtectKernelModules = true;
        ProtectControlGroups = true;
        ReadWritePaths = "/home/gitlabrunner/intranet/intranet_dev/files/";
        # Caps
        CapabilityBoundingSet = "";
        NoNewPrivileges = true;
        # Misc.
        LockPersonality = true;
        RestrictRealtime = true;
        PrivateMounts = true;
        PrivateUsers = true;
        MemoryDenyWriteExecute = true;
        SystemCallFilter = "~@clock @cpu-emulation @debug @keyring @memlock @module @mount @obsolete @raw-io @reboot @resources @setuid @swap";
        SystemCallArchitectures = "native";
        RestrictAddressFamilies = "AF_UNIX AF_INET AF_INET6";
    };

    # Only needed if secrets are not compiled INTO the application
    # environmentFile = "/opt/pm/secrets/.env";
  };
  }
```

[image: journalctl output]

[image: picture of the folder]

Thanks for help :D

Comment: [This maybe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13409/108618)?

Comment: No the loader was not the problem, but I solved it with changing the path to /opt/intranet. Don´t know why systemd can´t access the user home folder.

Comment: Nevertheless thank you for your help @KamilMaciorowski :D

Comment: So [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684074/108618) maybe.

Comment: Yes this could be the solution, but I think I just use the /opt/ folder for now.
Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, it's caused by `ProtectHome = true` in your service configuration. Either disable the protection by:

```
ProtectHome = false;
```

or keep the protection on and whitelist the relevant directories:

```
ProtectHome = "tmpfs";
BindPaths = "/home/gitlabrunner";
```